# How to use Conf struct in macroquad?

Tags: rust

I am trying to customize the behavior of macroquad in my Rust application, but I am having trouble understanding how to use the Conf struct. The documentation refers me to miniquad, but I'm not sure if I need to export both or how to fill in the fields of the Conf struct. Specifically, I am trying to change the window icon and other settings but I don't know how to do it. I have searched for similar questions, but I couldn't find any answers. Can someone please explain how to use the Conf struct in macroquad and how to customize the window icon and other settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [examples on the macroquad repo](https://github.com/not-fl3/macroquad/blob/fa486ff74caa8b94b2eeee3cad1da50eb393b53b/examples/window_conf.rs), you can pass a function returning your Conf struct as argument to the `main` macro

```rs
use macroquad::prelude::*;

fn window_conf() -> Conf {
    Conf {
        window_title: "Window Conf".to_owned(),
        fullscreen: true,
        ..Default::default()
    }
}

#[macroquad::main(window_conf)]
async fn main() {
    loop {
        clear_background(WHITE);
        next_frame().await
    }
}
```